# Mangled symbol table in Objective-C when linking static C++ library

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, linker, symbol-table

I have a class called options written in c++, here is the header info:

```
class Options {
public:
string filename;
string chunkDir;
string outFilename;
string inFilename;
BOOL   compress;
BOOL   extract;
BOOL   print;
BOOL   reconstruct;
int    bits;

Options(string inFilename);
Options(int argc, char** argv);
void unsupported(string s);
void setOptionsFromArguments(int argc, char** argv);
void validateOptionCombination();
int getBits() {
    return bits
};
```

};

In the objective-c section, I initialize Options like this:

```
Options *opts=new Options([fileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Now what happens is that if I pass the pointer to another C++ method it works fine, but if I actually try to access anything in the objective c side using, for example

opts->bits
or
opts->getBits()

It always returns the integer value for print

It looks like somehow the symbol table is getting mangled between the objective-c and C++ side, but I have no idea what I could have done to do cause this.

The code works even with Objective-C++ if I compile for the mac, and as long as C++ is calling C++ it seems to work so it's not like the memory is getting corrupted, it just looks like a symbol table issue.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, `BOOL` is a typedef to `signed char`. What definition are you using when compiling pure C++? If it's different, you'll get all sorts of weirdness, because the C++ code and the Objective-C++ code won't agree on the size or layout of the member variables.

Comment: That was it, I was using unsigned short.  I just changed the typedef name from BOOL to CBOOL in the C++ to avoid any potential future confusion.  Thanks.